# Add class to image onload - determine if landscape

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, addclass

I am trying to add a class to an image after determining if it is landscape or portrait. The problem I am having is that the class is being added to the `img` tag like this `img.landscape` which is obviously not registering properly. How can I properly achieve this: `<img class="landscape"` ?

```
$(data.images).each(function(j, imageURL){
        var thumbnail = new Image();
        thumbnail.src = imageURL;
        thumbnail.onload = function() {
            $('.images').append('<div class="image_mask"><a href="' + imageURL + '"><img src="' + imageURL + '"/></a></div>');
            if (thumbnail.width > thumbnail.height){
                $(this).addClass('landscape');
            }
        };
});
```

My previous solution was to include an if/else statement with the class added in the appended string, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of approaching this. Thanks!

EDIT--

http://jsfiddle.net/curly33/XeHzK/1/

Comment: Your problem might be unclear (at least it is for me). Maybe a fiddle could help demonstrate what you want.

Comment: I think you should use the if/else. It's pretty easy and easy to understand for later when someone fools with the program.

Comment: Why don't you add the class while appending image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to add a class to the `<img>` tag you're dynamically creating a few lines before?  If so, you can do so like this:

```
$('.image_mask img').addClass('landscape');
```

Since it's in a loop and you'll have multiple `div.image_mask`, use the array index `j` as a class qualifier:

```
$(data.images).each(function(j, imageURL){
        ...
        thumbnail.onload = function() {
            $('.images').append('<div class="image_mask image_mask' + j + '"><a href="' + imageURL + '"><img src="' + imageURL + '"/></a></div>');
            //                                                     ^^^^^^
            if (thumbnail.width > thumbnail.height){
                $('.image_mask' + j + ' img').addClass('landscape');
                //              ^^^^^^
            }
        };
});
```

**UPDATE**

Even though this was accepted, it feels clumsy to me to add class names like I originally suggested.  A cleaner approach would be to use the `j` array index variable in combination with jQuery's `eq` function to locate the relevant image mask:

```
$('.images .image_mask').eq(j).addClass('landscape');
```

..then do away with the whole adding of classes approach.

Comment: This is terribly unnecessary (class pollution), convoluted, and performs additional lookups every single iteration of the loop.  **Do not use this method.**  Add the class in your initial append.

Comment: @Travis - I've already updated my answer.  That said, I suggest you read the FAQ on when down-voting is appropriate, *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."*.  You may not like my (original) approach, but it hardly meets those criteria.  Thanks

Comment: @Madbreaks, I feel your answer is very sloppy, even your edit.  It performs unnecessary, and slow, work which could lead to serious performance implications depending on the context of use.  I use my downvotes conservatively, but your answer deserves it.

Comment: @Madbreaks, Just for perspective, I'm not just talking about performance impact.  What happens if there are multiple images sources, each with their own loop?  What about sectioned loading?  What if one image was added for some reason before the loop ran?  Your method would desync and collide in all these situations and more.  I'm not saying it doesn't work in this very limited, specific, situation, but it's definitely sloppy if it has the potential to break that easily.

Comment: *"I'm not saying it doesn't work in this very limited, specific, situation"*, great, then don't down-vote it. I didn't write the answer as an end-all approach to solving every possible permutation of the problem at hand, I wrote it to solve *this* problem.  It meets ops needs and *is not* slow (how many images do you think op's loading?).  If you disagree about how slow it is, post some numbers to back up your claim, I'd be interested to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in your string building

```
$(data.images).each(function(j, imageURL){
        var thumbnail = new Image();
        thumbnail.src = imageURL;
        thumbnail.onload = function() {
            var orientationClass = thumbnail.width > thumbnail.height ? "landscape" : "portrait";
            $('.images')
                .append(
                    '<div class="image_mask"><a href="' +
                    imageURL +
                    '"><img class="' +
                    orientationClass +
                    '" src="' +
                    imageURL +
                    '"/></a></div>'
                );
        };
});
```

**Edit: More options**

If you want to make it more verbose, but cleaner, you could build out the elements one by one:

```
var $img = $('<img />', {
    class: thumbnail.width > thumbnail.height ? "landscape" : "portrait",
    src: imageUrl
});

var $a = $('<a />', {
    href: imageUrl,
}).append($img);

var $div = $('<div />', {
    class: "image_mask"
}).append($a);

$('.images').append($div);
```

Or if you want to use the more efficient string building, but what it to be more readable/performant, you could do an array with a join:

```
var contents = [
    '<div class="image_mask"><a href="',
    imageURL ,
    '"><img class="',
    orientationClass,
    '" src="',
    imageURL,
    '"/></a></div>'];

$('.images').append(contents.join(''));
```

Comment: *"My previous solution was to include an if/else statement with the class added in the appended string"*

Comment: @dystroy, Hence "Just put it in your string building" -- and I also gave a ternary operation to make it a bit cleaner than a full blown if/else.